# Data preparation to show numbers in transit

Tags: r

In the end I want to create pretty [circos plots](https://github.com/jokergoo/circlize)  but to get there I need to show the number of people that go from A to B, and B to C and B to A etc.

My dataset:

```
#Generate some sample data:

proc<-sample(c("EMR","RFA","Biopsies"), 100, replace = TRUE)
#Sample dates
dat<-sample(seq(as.Date('2013/01/01'), as.Date('2017/05/01'), by="day"), 100)
#Generate 20 hospital numbers in no particular order:
Id<-sample(c("P43","P63","K52","G24","S55","D07","U87","P22","Y76","I92","P22","P02","U22415","U23","S14","O34","T62","J32","F63","T43"), 100, replace = TRUE)
df<-data.frame(proc,dat,Id)
```

If I am preparing the data for a Snakey plot I would do :

```
Sankey<-dcast(setDT(df)[, if(any(proc=="EMR"|proc=="RFA")) .SD, Id], Id~rowid(Id), value.var ="proc")
```

which would give me a nice table showing what happens to each patient at each timepoint in order.

But I want to go to the next step which is to find the number of patients that transit between each of the different `proc` types (ie "EMR", "RFA" and "Biopsies") so that I can get them into a format that circlize wants, namely (the frequency is made up here)

```
origin   destination frequency
EMR       RFA           14
EMR       Biopsies      4
EMR       EMR           10
RFA       RFA           24
RFA       Biopsies      42
RFA       EMR           1
Biopsies  RFA           3
Biopsies  Biopsies      6
Biopsies  EMR           16
```

or I suppose an alternative way to show it would be

```
             destination
               EMR            RFA      Biopsies
origin
 EMR           10             14         4
 RFA            1             24         42
 Biopsies      16             3          6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `dplyr` for that task, the heart of the analysis is the `lag` function to retrieve the last position of each patient, and the `summarise` function to count the cases.

The whole analysis would be done like this:

```r
# for reproducibility
set.seed(20170805)

# your data
proc<-sample(c("EMR","RFA","Biopsies"), 100, replace = TRUE)
#Sample dates
dat<-sample(seq(as.Date('2013/01/01'), as.Date('2017/05/01'), by="day"), 100)
#Generate 20 hospital numbers in no particular order:
Id<-sample(c("P43","P63","K52","G24","S55","D07","U87","P22","Y76","I92","P22","P02","U22415","U23","S14","O34","T62","J32","F63","T43"), 100, replace = TRUE)

# my approach using dplyr
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df <- data_frame(proc, dat, Id)

df %>% 
 # make sure that we progress in the direct order of time...
 arrange(dat) %>% 
 # for each patient:
 group_by(Id) %>%
 # find the last position
 mutate(origin = lag(proc, 1), destination = proc) %>%
 # for each origin, destination-pair...
 group_by(origin, destination) %>% 
 # summarise the number of pairs
 summarise(n = n()) %>% 
 # not really necessary, but gives a littlebit nicer output here...
 ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>      origin destination     n
#>       <chr>       <chr> <int>
#>  1 Biopsies    Biopsies     5
#>  2 Biopsies         EMR     8
#>  3 Biopsies         RFA    11
#>  4      EMR    Biopsies    11
#>  5      EMR         EMR    11
#>  6      EMR         RFA    10
#>  7      RFA    Biopsies     6
#>  8      RFA         EMR    12
#>  9      RFA         RFA     8
#> 10     <NA>    Biopsies     8
#> 11     <NA>         EMR     4
#> 12     <NA>         RFA     6
```

Comment: OK @David that gets the points. I figured out another answer too

Comment: Of course you could use data.table or any other format as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use a crafty way to do this basically by pasting all the columns together and then using the stringr package to seperate and then tabulate.

```
library(stringr)
Sankey<-dcast(setDT(df)[, if(any(proc=="EMR"|proc=="RFA")) .SD, Id], Id~rowid(Id), value.var ="proc")

    Sankey$x <- apply( Sankey[ , 2:ncol(Sankey)] , 1 , paste , collapse = "-" )
    library(stringr)
    myList<-unlist(str_extract_all(Sankey$x,"[A-Z|a-z]+-[A-Z|a-z]+"))

 table(myList)
```

Comment: Although now I think about it it isn't so crafty as it gives the wrong results hehe!! So much for creative problem solving.